# Vue: Access component object properties

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to use a statement within a element:

```
v-if="currentstep < maxStep"
```

The maxStep should be obtained from the number of components listed on my defauld export

```
  export default {
    name: 'step',
    data () {
      return {
        maxStep: 8,
        currentstep: 0
      }
    },
    components: {
      ConfigPublicador,
      ConfigServico,
      ModeloReceita,
      Integracoes,
      ConfigTema,
      ConfigApp,
      ConfigExtras,
      Assets,
      Revisao
    }
  }
```

Something like

```
maxStep = components.length
```

Any Ideias?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a code smell. But, you can get that value via `Object.keys(this.$options.components).length`.

Here's an example:

```js
const Foo = {
  template: '<div></div>',
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Foo },
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.count = Object.keys(this.$options.components).length;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="count > 0">
    There is at least one component
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry , but the $options.components lists all components, I'm looking for the internal reference only